# Heroku, Devise: Getting 'NoMethodError (undefined method `to_key' for :user:Symbol)'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, heroku, devise

I don't know when it happened but I'm getting this error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'to_key' for :user:Symbol)`

This behavior only happens on Heroku Cedar stack. I use Devise (1.4.2) for authentication via Facebook on Rails 3.1.0.rc6 and ruby 1.9.2-p290. It happens on the line with `sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)`. Here's my method:

```
def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']    

  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])


  if !authentication.nil?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t('devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: omniauth['provider'])

    sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
  elsif current_user
    current_user.authentications.create!(provider: omniauth['provider'], uid: omniauth['uid'])
    redirect_to profile_path, notice: I18n.t('devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: omniauth['provider'])
  else
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t('devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: omniauth['provider'])
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
    else
      session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before doing anything on local computer, try restarting heroku first:

```
$ cd your_app_directory
$ heroku restart
```

I had exactly the same problem and a simple restart fixed it.

Comment: I had the same problem but with `undefined method `encrypted_password='`. The restart worked for me too - thanks

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem of `NoMethodError (undefined method ' ... ` and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm receiving the same exact error; however, it only started after I configured my hostname in the omniauth.rb initializer as so:

OmniAuth.config.full_host = ‘http://hostname.com/subdirectory’

I've added this because I'm running Rails3 w/ Passenger in a subdirectory off my root domain. Perhaps you have the same override in place?

I still need to remedy Facebook's inability to handle a subdirectory callback (twitter properly preserves the subdirectory without the full_host override). Thoughts?

Comment: I do not have this override in my initializer. I do have `provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'` in the initializer.

Comment: Does Twitter work for you? It appears to be a path callback issue with Facebook from my end.

Comment: Fixed. It was an issue on my side. `authentication.user_id` field referenced a non-existing `user` record. These errors are really annoying. Once again, I really should write more tests :)

Comment: What was the actual change you made to your authentications controller? I'm still getting the error on this call: sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user). I realized my issues began after upgrading Ruby to 1.9.2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I cleaned the gem set for that project; I executed `bundle update`; I've restarted and exited all Ruby processes; At last I restarted the whole laptop; I deleted Ancestry gem ('cause to me these problems started after I installed it); I've deleted ActiveAdmin; re-installed those gems; re-starterd Pow couple times and suddenly it worked. Ruby is a magic language ;)